# Alternative to github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go for JWT in Go

Tags: go

We've been using [github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) for JWT-related processing in Go, however this project is clearly no longer maintained (last commit Jan. 2020, 87 open issues, explicit remarks from the community).

I would like recommendations for an alternative library to migrate my projects to.

I don't have unusual requirements. These are some points I'm looking for in a replacement candidate:

- sign and validate tokens (we use HMAC+SHA256)
- support custom claims
- support/allow custom `aud`
- allow to defer/skip validation (don't jump on the chair, I have a legit use case for this)

Additional requirements:

- it should be actively maintained and/or not have (an unreasonable amount of) open bugs, this is one of the main reasons I'm thinking to switch in the first place
- properly support Go modules (no `vX.Y.Z+incompatible` in my `go.mod`)

The following are code snippets that illustrate how I'm using my current JWT lib.

```
// custom claims example
        token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &MyClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
                msg := "unexpected signing method"
                logger.Error(msg)
                return nil, errors.New(msg)
            }
            return []byte(jwtSecret), nil
        })
```

```
// signing algo example
func (a *authorizer) jwtWithClientApp() *jwt.Token {
    if a.options.apiKey == "" {
        panic(...)
    }
    scope := "restricted"
    if a.options.scope != "" {
        scope = a.options.scope
    }

    return jwt.NewWithClaims(
        jwt.SigningMethodHS256,
        MyClaims{
            Scope: scope,
            ClientApp: &ClientApp{
                APIKey: a.options.apiKey,
                Name:   a.issuer,
            },
            StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
                ExpiresAt: time.Now().Add(a.options.expiry).UTC().Unix(),
                Issuer:    a.issuer,
                Subject:   a.options.apiKey,
            },
        },
    )
}
```

```
// defer/skip validation example
    parser := &jwt.Parser{}
    tok, _, err := parser.ParseUnverified(string(jwtaccess), &jwt.StandardClaims{})
    if err != nil {
        return "", -1, errors.Wrap(err, "failed to parse token")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are

- https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx
- https://github.com/square/go-jose

Both seem to be actively maintained and the second one is backed by the company *Square, Inc.*

If these don't fulfill your requirements please exclude them in your question.

Comment: Thanks! When I did my due diligence, `https://github.com/square/go-jose` seemed actually not maintained

Comment: I decided to go with `lestrrat-go/jwx`, it's a pretty good lib and it seems actively maintained. Can't upvote tho bc I have no more rep... >.<